# A few jsPlumb issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I recently started using jsPlumb to make a UI for a client, but I have come across two issues that I can't seem to solve.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ugxopksz/

The first is my endpoints and connections not being repainted when I resize the window. The site this is going on has some responsive design in it. I tried doing the whole

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
});
```

But that doesn't do crap. I don't get an error from it, but it doesn't do anything at all.

My second problem is I cannot find anyway to specify more than one source for one connection. Something like:

```
instance.connect({
        source:"oneT",
        target:"center",
        anchor:[[1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 80], [0, 0.5, 0, 0, 7, -40]]
});
```

Unless I can declare some array and create a loop that will make that block of code for each element in the array. The reason I am looking for that is this UI is pulling from a database and creating each outer element, since they can change I'd like it to be able to handle if database changes occur I don't have to go in and manually add new elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For First Question:**

Making use of list elements(li tag) is not preferable for connection. Instead you can make of div elements and try it. Resize of windows also fails to repaint since the **li** tags doesn't have proper positions. From [**Doc's**](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html#container) it is clear that element having position absolute will behave normal under all conditions.

Have a look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/4ar7o55q/) for connecting DIV elements and also for repaint option on resizing  window.

**For Second Question:**

For now jsPlumb doesn't support multiple id's for source parameter so you have no other option than to loop them in an array as:

```
var trg = 'center';
var src = ['oneT','twoT','threeT'];    

for(var i=0;i<src.length;i++)
{
    jsPlumb.connect({
                source: src[i],
                target: trg,
                connector: [ "Flowchart", {cornerRadius:1} ],
                paintStyle:{ lineWidth:5, strokeStyle:'#3E2522' },
                anchors: [[1.02, 0.5, 0, 1],
                    [-0.02, 0.5, 0, 0]],
                endpointStyle: { radius:0.5 }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will see how divs work with keeping the idea that this content will be added and removed. I guess figuring that out will be better than working against jsPlumb.

Comment: I finally got time to fully implement your suggestions. Everything works great, but it still won't repaint. I have changed to divs and gave them all absolute positions. Would using percentages to place them be working against that?

Comment: Update in jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have created the connections using a seperate jsPlumb instance you have  to repaint the jsPlumb components using the same instance.
Change the following line

```
jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
```

to

```
instance.repaintEverything();
```

[Click here for updated jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Loex442y/)